# How can I get the click event in branch.io webhook?

Tags: deep-linking, webhooks, branch.io

In branch.io there is a way to receive the click event in my webhook endpoint?
I need a way to measure how many users clicks on the deep-link but didn´t install the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick update: Branch now *does* support the `click` event via webhook! You can select it as an option when configuring your webhook on the Branch dashboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We (Branch) don't offer the click event via webhook.  The volume is just too high and the cost would be prohibitive.  You can find full documentation on our webhooks on our docs site: https://dev.branch.io/recipes/webhooks_and_exporting_data/#register-webhook-on-dashboard

If you control the environment where the link will be served you may be able to gather this information yourself.  For instance on the web you can use javascript to create event listeners that will send a message to your api whenever a link is clicked.  Here's a doc on how to do it from w3schools - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp.

Good luck!